# Allow Room Owners in chat room to be pinged as a group

Tags: feature-request, chat

Is it possible to add the ability for Room Owners (ROs), as a group, to be "pinged" in the same manner that a normal user can be pinged? At the moment, someone can ping me with `@Ffisegydd`. **I propose that ROs should be ping-able with a similar "group" ping, say `@RoomOwners` or `@ROs`.**

This would allow people to quickly get in touch with any ROs that are present, if they need to discuss something.

To avoid abuse in busier channels, this ability could be room-dependent, *i.e.* busier rooms could turn it off in their settings if they so wish.

Comment: The roomowner's are one click away under [info](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) or can be noticed in the room by their names being italic. For regulars the room owners are mostly known so I have the feeling this is only a benefit for new chatusers that join a chatroom they never visited before. I can see some value in it but wouldn't be my highest priority....

Comment: @rene it's still a schlep. Additionally, what about RoomOwnersInternal, for room owners to only talk to each other? :)

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus - Speaking in the room will undoubtedly be observed by one of the room owners.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus - And as an owner of two of them, with 10 times your use, I can assure you it is a majority of the time.

Comment: As an owner of a room where we already discourage regular @ pings, I really don't understand what problem this is trying to solve.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus - Your statement was intentionally demeaning, "as the owner of one of the most popular rooms on SO". Moreover, the nuance here is not really worthy of debate. Yes, there was probably a very small amount of messages which were not seen by any room owner. However, the percent is probably infinitely small and can be considered none. In the Javascript room, for example, which has a total of 2 million messages, 1.3 million of them are from owners. This would indicate that more than 1 in 2 messages are from a room owner, giving them ample time to read a non owner message.

Comment: @TravisJ If you choose to take his statement as demeaning, then I suppose that's up to you, but I didn't read it that way. Incidentally, you are taking evidence from one particular room which is, I think, particularly busy, but the SE chat system is more than just your JS room :)

Comment: @Ffisegydd - It is 40% in python, still pretty close to 1 in two messages. These are rather tedious to compute, and I do not want to end up compiling the percent for every room in the entire exchange. I believe my point stands, **Speaking in the room will undoubtedly be observed by one of the room owners.** Moreover, the comment was little more than an ad hominem implication and I believe that is demeaning.

Comment: A restriction could be added so that one user can use this feature every 2 hours (or even longer).

Comment: [popcorn time](http://weknowgifs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/psyche-eating-popcorn-gif.gif)

Comment: @TravisJ That's not what *ad hominem* means.

Comment: @TylerH - The prefix was an implication that since he was an owner of a popular room, and presumably I was not, I did not know what I was talking about. However, that was not the case.

Comment: @TravisJ I can see no such implication in Zero's comments above. It seems you are inferring that which was not implied.

Comment: @TylerH - Aside from your observation of minutia, what is your opinion of this proposal?

Comment: @TravisJ I haven't noticed or commented on any minutiae, but I don't think it's necessary. I think it would be an annoyance to room owners more than a boon. I don't think the one chatroom I visit, HTML/CSS/Web Design, is very active, so I don't know how often room owners are needed and absent in other rooms.

Answer (score 13):

There would have to be some sort of restrictions, for instance, so that people can't spam every room owner for no reason.

But, this would be a cool feature, coming from the JS room where us Room Owners are pretty close and often chat just as bros and bro-ettes (Mandatory for our lady Badger)

Answer (score 13):

I disagree.

It makes the place messy, room owners gets unnecessary pings. And of which when they don't read it, obsolete messages reside in their inbox, likely to have been handled by another room owner.

There is no pressing need to turn the room owners into a special crew of the room. If something demands review from the room owners, the current system (forcing users to find the list of room owners and ping them at once) works, is not overly problematic, and works. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

I dislike this personally. The fact that *a few* rooms engages in active room owner - user interaction doesn't deem such feature necessary. It's also not appropriate as, being the only group-pingable group, will introduce abuse and misuse which annoys not only a person, but every room owner. It will also introduce discrimination to users who aren't room owners, especially when users are in chat rooms to get help quickly.

Answer (score 9):

While I do understand the reasoning behind this idea, I don’t think it’s really a feature that’s generally useful or even not annoying.

The original idea for this suggestion came from the desire to organize a meeting with all room owners. As such, it was desired to ping *all* room owners, so that *all of them* see the message and have a chance to respond to it.

Now, apart from such organizational reasons (which are—let’s be honest—pretty rare), a normal “attention of a room owner” ping would hardly ever need to involve from than a single room owner. In contrast, having *all* room owners pinged for a (probably) trivial reason is likely bothersome to ROs that simply aren’t around at the moment. In the Python room, we actually tried to look for candidates in other timezones so there is always one around at any time for the exact reason, that other ROs do not need to get involved. Now if there was a permanent ping that stayed around on the whole network until I dismiss it, it would probably be a bit annoying.

So such a “room owner ping” would need to clear as soon as *any* room owner responded to the ping. And at this point, it sounds more like some kind of report system. But more importantly, the original intent won’t be fulfilled, so it’s probably not a solution to the actual problem. And I don’t really think there is an actual need for such a solution. As rene said: the list of room owners is just a click away, and for those rare occasions where you need attention from all of them, it’s not such a big problem to actually ping them all individually.

Comment: While the idea for this came to me with "aww dammit I wish I could ping everyone at once", I then thought that it would be a useful tool for users to quickly get the attention of a present RO if they needed it. As such it would possibly act as the "report system" you describe where it could be removed when answered. It is, IMO, a better solution than looking through the RO list saying "Oh well she's not around, he just said goodbye, I dunno ummm... let's try and work out which RO spoke last based on the fadedness of their avatar in the list by cross-correlating with the RO list..."

Answer (score 6):

Most times when something has to happen "quickly" it is someone trying to meet some last minute deadline and looking for someone else to help them finish. Often these are also questions on the main site which have a sense of urgency and entitlement.

I do not think that allowing this urgency to play out in the form of pinging every single owner in a room is going to be beneficial. It is already common in chat for owners to get randomly pinged by a user who has entered the room for the first time.

Further, and as noted in comments above in this question, the owners list is available one click away in room info. Anyone wishing to contact one or all of the owners could simply find the list or user there and manually do this. It seems highly unlikely that every owner would need to be contacted at the same time very often.

For those with bro and bro-ette -*mances*, I get it. However, in those situations most people review the transcript because they are highly experienced with the chat system. It doesn't seem very necessary to ping all of them at once.

In addition to these points, there is also an easy way to get the attention of other owners in the room, and that is through the use of pinning messages. This method works very well, and is used often in a majority of chat rooms.

I think this feature would introduce the possibility of abuse, is already available to accomplish in the current system, and would not solve any pressing problems.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this would be a useful feature. I have seen similar feature in topcoder competition chat room, where the question writer (this would be a different person every time) can be pinged with `@writer`, after the competition to discuss.

In our case, there 10 ROs for the Python room. Out of the ten, I will be available when all other ROs might be sleeping (there is an yellow puppy which never does this though), for a tiny time window (Mornings, Indian Standard Time). If somebody wants to bring up something to the room owners attention, they can simply ping with `@ROs`. Since most people won't be active, checking chat every minute would not be very productive. So, a ping like this would be helpful to bring the attention to the chat window.

The advantages would be

1. Available ROs can engage immediately, if there is a concern raised.
2. New people don't have to find the list of ROs from `info`, find the ROs who are online and ping one of them. (Most people don't like to do that, they simply will leave a message in the chat, which might get unnoticed over time) *If it is something which should be notified to an RO, all the ROs deserve to be notified.*
3. ROs need not have to scroll through pages of chat to find something important.

**Note:** Since [kick-muting is available now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239226/235416), users who abuse this feature can be given a warning first and if they don't listen, they can be kick-muted.

Comment: As noted in my answer in this same thread, "The fact that a few rooms engages in active room owner - user interaction doesn't deem such feature necessary." I do appreciate the current interaction going on in the Python room, but the same can be achieved by writing a userscript for the participants.